# How thick a gold finish on a pcb for wire bonding?

Tags: pcb, gold, wirebonding

As a partial reparation for my previous [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/138068/good-gerber-viewers?noredirect=1#comment279438_138068) today.
Please allow this rather esoteric/ but on topic question.
I was sending out a pcb that will have gold wire bonding pads.
It was a option at our board [house](http://www.4pcb.com/).  I got a call when I was requesting a quote.

"How thick do you want the soft gold bonding layer?"
"I have no idea." I said, which is my normal response.
"What's your "standard" thickness.?", I asked.
I was shifted to engineering. 
30-50 micro inches was the answer, after a nice discussion.
(It's always a pleasure to talk with the engineer's.)
So that's what I ordered.
I could order a thicker layer.
Has anyone done this?
I'll be wire bonding soon, so I can let you know if it works.

Edit:  Well I got the quote back and my jaw dropped.  The price is more than $2k for a few pcb's.  For that cost I could evaporate my own Ni and gold layers.

Edit 2: (Adding more to the question.)
So the reason for the high price is that the board house needed to send it outside for processing.  I asked for quotes on their other types of Gold finishes.

The first is called Deep Gold.  This is an electrolytic process and puts down 30 u inches of gold.  (I don't know if there is any underlying Nickel.)  This is also called hard gold and from limited reading I don't think it works for wire bonding.

The second is Immersion Gold.  or ENIG and puts down 3-10 u in (75-250 nm) of gold over a thicker nickel layer.  Again from limited reading it seems that one can not wire bond to this with gold.  But maybe with aluminum.  (Though there can problems with the Al/Au interface.)

And my final crazy idea is to make a mask for my pcb and evaporate my own Ni/Au layer.

Comment: @mkeith, thanks, I think I'm getting gold over copper.  I've got an expert showing me how to do the wire bonding... hey I should ask him how thick!

Comment: Gold over copper will corrode. The gold will peel right off the copper after a couple weeks. Guess how I know.

Comment: @ThePhoton, Interesting.  Did you have a board house make it for you?  I'm still waiting for a firm quote from advanced circuits, I'll ask them if they do a nickle layer in between.  (Certainly they must know how to do it.)

Comment: Are you ball bonding? (Au) or wedge bonding (Al)?

Comment: @GeorgeHerold There's a place in PA that offers training in wire bonding, next course is in early Dec.  I think all gold over copper *requires* a barrier layer of some kind (usually Ni, but I guess other things would work). Unfortunately Ni is a bit magnetic so that that doesn't always work in sensitive applications.

Comment: @placeholder, (as is usual) my answer is I have no idea.  I was hoping to just do this and not have to learn all about it.  (but now that looks like a fools dream.)  I just ordered the 2nd ed,. of "Wire Bonding in Microelectronics"

Comment: @SpehroPefhany,  Thanks,  I'll be doing this at the CNF (Cornell nano-fab) and there is a wire bonding expert there.  I talked with him a bit a few months ago, and just sent him an email asking about options.

Comment: $2K? Wow. Hard to imagine how the makers of LCD modules, toys etc. can do COB if they are paying prices like that. ;-)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, well Adv. Circuits has to send it outside for processing, (which explains the price.)  As the Photon said below there seems to be a big push to reduce the amount of gold (for obvious cost reasons.) And there are newer processes using palladium.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold, If you were asking for a quick turnaround (like 5 days or less), that will interact with the external process to bump the price up. Say you requested 5-day turn with gold plating. If they need 2 days to turn the plating around with the external vendor, then they have to treat the rest of the build like a 3-day turn.

Comment: @ThePhoton, It was still over $2k at 4 weeks.

Answer (score 2):

According to documents I have from a PCB vendor, a typical spec for wire-bondable electrolytic soft gold is and 1.97 \$\mu\$in (min) gold over 188 \$\mu\$in (min) nickel. These are called out as IPC minimum values, though I don't have the IPC documents in front of me.

ENEPIG (electroless nickel, electroless palladium, immersion gold) plating can also produce a wire-bondable surface. A typical spec for that is 197 \$\mu\$in nickel, 12 \$\mu\$in palladium and 1.1 \$\mu\$in gold. Again these are all minimum values.

Recently I had success with a design that spec'ed the gold thickness as 25-30 \$\mu\$in, but really you don't want a very thick gold layer because excessive gold does bad things to solder joint reliability.

Comment: Thanks,  I've spent the morning reading all about ENEPIG and all sorts of other wire bonding stuff.  The soft gold thickness was 30 u in. (1 u in = 25nm) the reason for the large price in the quote was because they needed to send it out for processing.  Does the place you used do small proto-type quantities?  OK I'm stopping here and just editing my question.

Comment: Most PCB shops, afaik, will send boards out to a plating shop for gold plating. This might be related to the environmental/safety issues with some of the chemicals involved in plating processes. Certain processes might be easier to get done in-house than others. If you visit chat I could drop names of a couple of shops I've used.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I want to answer my own question.
Well, it's not my answer at all. 
Credit goes to JL, the first response [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=&hl=en#!topic/sci.electronics.design/N0hQo_RNKsY).
And then while chatting 'The Photon' found the following [link](http://www.compexcorp.com/mst.html). 
Which looks just about perfect, for prototype wire bonding. 
(I hope someone will give him another +1 for me.)